For Behave step files, can I force the default matcher strategy if the file has no ‘use_step_matcher’ statement?
I’m working on a test automation project that uses the Behave framework. There are ~100 step files in the ‘features/steps’ folder.
I have created a new step file with the project’s first use of the “re” matcher.
use_step_matcher("re")
This is the first file in the project where the matcher is being manually set. All existing step files rely on the default “parse” matcher.
When I run a feature file with one of my new “re” steps and an existing “parse” step, it now errors, saying the existing “parse” step is Undefined.
Step example:
When this step uses “parse” strategy
When this step uses “re” strategy
ERROR on step ‘When this step uses “parse”’: UNDEFINED

The error is resolved if I manually set the matcher to “parse” in the step file of the failing step
use_step_matcher("parse")
My question:
Am I going to have to now add 'use_step_matcher("parse")' to all of the ~100 existing steps files?
Is there a way I can configure the project so all step files will use “parse” if there is no ‘use’ statement in the file?
Note, I tried setting use_step_matcher("parse") globally in the features/environment file, didn’t solve the issue. The use_step_matcher("re") in the new step file overwrote that when the test ran.
